# can pytest ignore a specific warning?

Tags: python, pytest

I'd like pytest to ignore the RemovedInDjango20Warning.

I currently have this in pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore:RemovedInDjango20Warning
```

And that allows pytest to run, but does not suppress the warnings.

If I add a second colon, I get a lot of "INTERNAL ERROR" messages.

If I add a third colon, the tests run, but do not suppress the warnings.

I am afraid to add a fourth colon :)

~

I've also tried being more specific about the error:

```
ignore:django.RemovedInDjango20Warning
```

and

```
ignore:django.utils.deprecation.RemovedInDjango20Warning
```

and while those run, I'm still warned every time.

The INTERNALERRORs that I get are:

```
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/chris/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/warnings.py", line 246, in _getcategory
INTERNALERROR>     cat = getattr(m, klass)
INTERNALERROR> AttributeError: module 'django' has no attribute 'RemovedInDjango20Warning'
INTERNALERROR> 
INTERNALERROR> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
INTERNALERROR> 
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/website-36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 196, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0

[long traceback snipped]

INTERNALERROR>     raise _OptionError("unknown warning category: %r" % (category,))
INTERNALERROR> warnings._OptionError: unknown warning category: 'django.RemovedInDjango20Warning'
```

Comment: What you have looks correct ...

Comment: According to the documentation (https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html) the correct syntax seems to be two colons (::) (not "comma"). Can you share what "internal error" messages you get in that case?

Comment: @LaurentBristiel you are correct regarding colons vs commas -- I was sloppy in writing my post, I will update.  thanks.

Answer (score 48):

While taking a second look based on @LaurentBristiel 's comments, I realized that I need two colons, PLUS the full path to the exception, so

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::django.utils.deprecation.RemovedInDjango20Warning
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: Thanks! And I have to highlight the importance of **full path** to the exception. This is not needed for standard exception (like e.g. `FutureWarning` and so on) but necessary for custom warnings (like e.g. `SettingWithCopyWarning` from pandas in my case).

Comment: The two colons are due to the [Warning Filter format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#describing-warning-filters).