# How to ignore SAWarning in pytest

Tags: sqlalchemy, pytest, warnings

I get this warning:

/app/facelo/extensions.py:36: SAWarning: DELETE statement on table 'trials' expected to delete 1 row(s); 0 were matched.  Please set confirm_deleted_rows=False within the mapper configuration to prevent this warning.

I want to ignore it. I tried to use:

```
@pytest.mark.filterwarnings("ignore::SAWarning")
```

It gives me:

```
INTERNALERROR> warnings._OptionError: unknown warning category: 'SAWarning'
```

So it doesn't work because pytest doesn't know this warning. How can Ignore this warning?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this question, [can pytest ignore a specific warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59617394/can-pytest-ignore-a-specific-warning) , they supply the full path to the exception.  They are using a configuration file but try that with the SAWarning using mark.

```py
@pytest.mark.filterwarnings("ignore::sqlalchemy.exc.SAWarning")
```