# Ignore/catch a warning for a specific line of a unit test - pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to write a unit test that calls a function repeatedly and testing what happens if it gets run multiple times with the same inputs. A by-product of the function is that there are some warnings that are emitted whenever it is run. This results in code like:

```
with pytest.warns(RuntimeWarning, match='depends on the pytest parametrization'):
    output = func(**kwargs)
```

This gets really verbose when I use `pytest.mark.parametrize`, which then now results in multiple if `pytest.warns(...)` type code.

Can I specify to just ignore all warnings that are emitted in line for just a specific line in the unit test? E.g. something like this

```
with pytest.ignore_all_warnings():
    output = func(**kwargs)
```

##### Other Ways to Ignore Warnings

I am aware of [can pytest ignore a specific warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59617394/can-pytest-ignore-a-specific-warning) and in general ways to ignore warnings, but those ignore across files, and functions. I would like to just ignore warnings in a specific line of the unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#testing-warnings), you can use the `catch_warnings` context manager to limit changes in the warnings filter to a code block. If you use it with an unspecific filter that ignores all warnings, you can suppress all warnings in a single line :

```py
import warnings
...

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    # ignore all warnings
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
    do_stuff()
```

This is not specific to `pytest`, but can be used in any code.